# Finder on macOS: Search works by default with “Name matches” instead of “Name contains”

Tags: macos, search, finder

Is there any possibility to change default behaviour of Search text box in Finder to search with “Name contains” instead of “Name matches”?
I know there is this possibility in advanced searching criteria but that is way too lengthy and usually I just need to quickly find some files by part of the filename.

macOS Catalina v10.15.5

Comment: Yeah, that's irritating. It used to do 'contains' by default until about El Cap or so. If no-one here picks up on this in a day or two, flag it to be migrated to Ask Different for a second shot.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I just wanted to flag it to be migrated to Ask Different but there is unfortunately no option for moving there. There are only other sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: You flag for moderator attention & ask in the text box.

Comment: This seems to be the default behaviour in macOS Monterey (not 100% sure it was integrated in macOS Big Sur) if you don't mind upgrading your macOS version

Comment: You are right, @tama. It works in macOS Monterey as a default option, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Find Any File can do this, an it's only $7.99:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/find-any-file-faf/id402569179?mt=12

FYI I haven't tried it myself, but the developer website screenshot shows searching by Contains:

http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php

Comment: 8 bucks for something that used to be the default setting, & if you want a 3rd party app can be done for free with [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12)   - I'm not exactly sold.

Comment: I have to agree with @Tetsujin. In the end, using another app would be more complicated than using Finder search. It would be sufficient for me to have an option where I could set default condition for the search box.